# Ignore a column in MS ACCESS query if the WHERE clause is not set

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

**Problem**

I've got a dropdown list, which shows all the Article_Group_ID's that are linked to a specific brand, using the following Query:

```
SELECT TbArticle.Article_Group_ID, TbArticle.Article_Brand_ID
FROM TbArticle
GROUP BY TbArticle.Article_Group_ID, TbArticle.Article_Brand_ID, 
HAVING (((TbArticle.Article_Brand_ID)=1))
```

This works as expected, it returns the following:

Query results

| Article_Brand_ID | Article_Group_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

But, if a user does not wish to specify a specific Article_Brand_ID, the query results look like this:

Query

| Article_Brand_ID | Article_Group_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

As you can see, the same Article_Group_ID is returned three times. Because of this, the user now sees the same group three times, instead of just once. If I were to remove the Article_Brand_ID from the query, the results would look like this:

| Article_Group_ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

Is there any way to achieve the same behavior, by "ignoring" the Article_Brand_ID column, if it's WHERE clause is not set?

**Database layout**

TbArticle

| Article_Brand_ID | Article_Group_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

Comment: If you want only Brand 1 to display even if user does not specify anything then that criteria must be in query. But the parameter shows as hard-coded in the query, not user provided. So what you want cannot be done with a single combobox. Perhaps you should consider cascading combobox - 2 comboboxes where second combobox list is dependent on choice in first. This is a common topic.

Answer (score 0):

A single query cannot return a variable number of columns.  So, strictly speaking you cannot do what you want with a single query.  However, if you are willing to accept the second column as `NULL` when the brand is not provided, then you can adjust the aggregation.

Let me denote the parameter by `?`:

```
SELECT a.Article_Group_ID,
       IIF(? IS NOT NULL, a.Article_Brand_ID, NULL) as Article_Brand_ID
FROM TbArticle as a
WHERE a.Article_Brand_ID = ? OR
      ? IS NULL
GROUP BY a.Article_Group_ID, 
         IIF(? IS NOT NULL, a.Article_Brand_ID, NULL);
```

Note:  It is usually better to filter *before* aggregating (i.e. using `WHERE`) rather than filtering afterwards (i.e. using `HAVING`).